# How to fix hamburger menu in ASP.NET MVC when using Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-bootstrap

The ASP.NET MVC default template includes a hamburger menu wired up to be visible when the page is viewed on smaller-width devices. It relies not only on bootstrap.css but also bootstrap.js for its ability to show/hide the nav menu.

With AngularJS we need to use ui-bootstrap.js and are advised to exclude Twitter's native bootstrap.js.

For the most part that works fine, but the hamburger menu dies. What's the most elegant way to way to wire up the hamburger menu to behave the same as before?

Comment: what does "the hamburger menu dies" mean, exactly?

Comment: Clicking on the hamburger yields nothing. Usually it should act as a toggle to show/hide the menu but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I played with this further and uib-collapse seems like a good solution.

Firstly, add a toggle variable in the button's ng-click event.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="navMenuIsCollapsed = !navMenuIsCollapsed">
```

Secondly, apply uib-collapse on the menu element using that variable.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="navMenuIsCollapsed">
```

This works with UI Bootstrap v 0.14.3. Older versions may have the uib-collapse directive named differently.